# Category ID's order

Tags: catalog, category

For example I have a product called `Nike shoes` and it has categories `Catalog > Shoes > Men`.

What I need is just to get the name of the last category (`Men`). At first glance it can be retrieved very easily:

```
$cat = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$name= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( end($cat) )->getName();
```

But there is a big problem, function `getCategoryIds()` return array of category ID's sorted numerically - so if last category (e.g. `Men`) has smaller index then previous one (e.g. `Shoes`) - I'll get incorrect result (`Shoes`).

Question: how to get list of category ID's sorted in the same way as on "Manage Categories" page? Or just how to get the last category?

Thank you

Comment: The problem here is that you can have a product nested *n*-depth in any number of categories. Are you trying to get this as a function of maximum depth or the *current* category that the product is being viewed within?

Comment: I want to get the name of category of a product, but only the one that has highest n-depth. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope someone comes up with a better solution, because I'm pretty sure mine if far from being perfect, sub-optimal, and VERY hacky. Anyway, when I need the most specific category related to a product, I do something like this:

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
$collection->getSelect()->order('level DESC')->limit(1);

$name = $collection->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

By sorting the categories by their level, you will get the most specific one by calling `getFirstItem()`. Hopefully there's a better/easier way to do it which I'm not aware of, but this one works for sure.

I should note that, in case you have 2+ categories which are on the same level, you will get only one of them, specifically the first one which appears in the collection. The result is not so easy to predict, but it was usually good enough for what I needed to do.

Comment: According to the OP they need the maximum n-depth, perhaps this is good enough. You can also chain via fluent interface the addAttributes, and you can get the collection without specifically referring to `getResourceModel` via `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()`

Comment: I edited it, but it still doesn't look much prettier :-) Still, it gets the job done

Comment: Thank you guys, it works, but adds a few dozens of queries to catalog page.

Comment: In what way does it add a few dozen queries?

Comment: @philwinkle I add this code to every product in catalog, and very usually all of them have mixed categories.